# Image is not displaying after loading from database?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm quite new to react native. I have a user with a profile picture that I'm trying to display on screen, when printing to my console `snapshot.val().imageURL` the correct url is displayed using this:

```
var profImage = 'https://www.placeholdit.com';
var user = authFB.currentUser;
 if (user) {
   database.ref('users').child(user.uid).once('value')
   .then((snapshot) => profImage = snapshot.val().imageURL)
   .catch(error => console.log(error))
   } else {
     console.log("No user")
 }
```

I assign that url to `profImage` and try to set my image uri to that variable:

```
<Avatar
    large
    rounded
    source={{ uri: profImage }}
    onPress={() => alert(profImage)}
    activeOpacity={0.7}
    containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 12 }}
/>
```

However, my image container remains blank. Does this have to do that when the render function is run, the url hasn't been retrieved thus the component display is blank? Do I use `this.setState` to update the component? If so, what is the proper way to do so?

Here is the relevant part of my component:

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Profile",
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            borderBottomWidth: 0,
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
            color: 'black'
        },
    }
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            image: null,
            uploading: null,
        }
    }

    render() {

        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        let { image } = this.state;

        var profImage = 'https://www.placeholdit.com';
        var user = authFB.currentUser;
        if (user) {
        database.ref('users').child(user.uid).once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => profImage = snapshot.val().imageURL)
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
        } else {
        console.log("No user")
        }

        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.profileTopContainer}>
                    <Avatar
                        large
                        rounded
                        source={{ uri: img }}
                        onPress={() => alert(profImage)}
                        activeOpacity={0.7}
                        containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 12 }}
                    />
                    <Text
                        style={styles.usernameText}
                    >
                        Jordan Lewallen
                    </Text>
                    <TouchableHighlight
                        onPress={this._pickImage}>
                        <Text
                            style={styles.userMinutes}
                        >
                            Choose a profile picture
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>

                    {this._maybeRenderImage()}
                    {this._maybeRenderUploadingOverlay()}
                    {
                        (image)
                        ? <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 250, height: 250 }} />
                        : null
                    }

                </View>
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
 <Avatar
                    large
                    rounded
                    source={{ uri: img }}
                    onPress={() => alert(profImage)}
                    activeOpacity={0.7}
                    containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 12 }}
                />
```

replace with

```
 <Avatar
                    large
                    rounded
                    source={{ uri: profImage }}
                    onPress={() => alert(profImage)}
                    activeOpacity={0.7}
                    containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 12 }}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you call the async request inside your render method itself.
When your render method execute you request for imageUrl which is a async call and takes time to resolve and update the value of profImage variable. At that time your render method is finished its execution and set the placeholder. 
If you need this to be done you should keep this profImage in your component state. So once the state is updated your render method will be called again and update the UI with new image.

Try this!

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Profile",
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
        color: 'black'
    },
}
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        image: null,
        uploading: null,
    }
}

componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
    var profImage = 'https://www.placeholdit.com';
    var user = authFB.currentUser;
    if (user) {
    database.ref('users').child(user.uid).once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => this.setState({ image: snapshot.val().imageURL }))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
    } else {
      this.setState({ image: 'https://www.placeholdit.com' });
      console.log("No user")
    }
}

render() {

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    let { image } = this.state;

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.profileTopContainer}>
                <Avatar
                    large
                    rounded
                    source={{ uri: image }}
                    onPress={() => alert(profImage)}
                    activeOpacity={0.7}
                    containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 12 }}
                />
                <Text
                    style={styles.usernameText}
                >
                    Jordan Lewallen
                </Text>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={this._pickImage}>
                    <Text
                        style={styles.userMinutes}
                    >
                        Choose a profile picture
                    </Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                {this._maybeRenderImage()}
                {this._maybeRenderUploadingOverlay()}
                {
                    (image)
                    ? <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 250, height: 250 }} />
                    : null
                }

            </View>
            }
```

Comment: this logic makes complete sense! however, the example you provided doesn't work, I get a `can't find variable: img` error. I actually use the `image` component state variable name for the actual image upload (needs to change for semantics) but for the sake of clarity could you make your state variable that I need to use something like `stackOverflowImage` to help differentiate? Thanks so far!

Comment: this is odd, now it's giving me a fuss about `JSON value <null> of type NSNull cannot be converted to a valid URL` so it seems like `image` isn't being set to the url pulled from the database? @csath

Comment: i guess what we're seeing makes sense, since it throws the error even before the async function can finish? ..right?

Comment: snapshot.val().imageURL may not give the URL.You need to set the correct variable name here I guess.